# How to run Testcafe Saucelabs in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, automation, automated-tests, testcafe, saucelabs

How to configure saucelabs with testcafe in Jenkins with proxy settings and all, even I have used testcafe saucelabs plugin as well, please inform me where to do those config and how.

Answer (score 3):

Integration with Sauce Labs is described in the [Run Tests on Sauce Labs with Travis CI](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/continuous-integration/travis-and-sauce-labs.html) topic. Integration with Jenkins is described in the [Integrate TestCafe with Jenkins](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/continuous-integration/jenkins.html) topic. If you want to combine both approaches, you should just use Jenkins instead of Travis CI to run the `testcafe "saucelabs:Chrome@beta:Windows 10" tests/index-test.js` command.

And if by "proxy settings and the all" you mean TestCafe settings (including the `proxy` one), they can be stored in the `.testcaferc.json` configuration file (please refer to the [Configuration File](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/using-testcafe/configuration-file.html) topic) or passed as command-line arguments wherever you run `testcafe` from your CI script.